# Magento is not sending newsletter due to cron job

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, newsletter, time, email-scheduler

I can't send newsletter because of cron job is not taking correct scheduled time in cron log

`Aoe_schedular` given error like

> No heartbeat task found. Check if cron is configured correctly

My scheduled time

[image: my scheduled]

And log in **var/log/cron.log** is

> 2016-09-01T06:17:29+00:00 DEBUG (7): Generated schedule. Newest task
>   is scheduled at "2016-09-01 06:36:00". (Duration: 0.4 sec)

Answer (score 0):

cron job runs on your server time so it may possible that it differ from your magento store time check difference between this two timezone and make time accordingly for your cronjob

Comment: ok , i want to know, its not affect the newsletter sending option, then why newsletter not sent